# Divide the values of two rdds in spark (python)

Tags: python, apache-spark, rdd, division, bigdata

I have these two Key-value RDDs in spark:

```
rdd1 = [(u'Key1', 4), (u'Key2', 6), (u'Key3', 10)]
rdd2 = [(u'Key1', 4), (u'Key2', 3), (u'Key3', 2)]
```

And I looking the spark function to get the division of the values: (rdd3= (rdd1/rdd2))

In this case:

```
rdd3 = [(u'Key1', 1), (u'Key2', 2), (u'Key3', 5)]
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can `join` and `mapValues`:

```
rdd1.join(rdd2).mapValues(lambda x: x[0] / x[1])
```